# mkbundle generated binary causes SIGSEGV on ARMv7h, while running fine in Mono

Tags: mono, mkbundle, archlinux-arm

I'm currently testing Mono in archlinux on ARMv7h. For a start, I tested this simple program:

```
// test.cs
using System;

public class Test {
  public static void Main(string[] args) {
    Console.WriteLine("I'm working.");
  }
}
```

I use Mono as a native package installed via `pacman`, not cross-compiled. When run, it behaves as intended:

```
mcs test.cs
mono test.exe
I'm working.
```

When I try to bundle this assembly using `mkbundle`, it compiles without any errors:

```
mkbundle --deps test.exe -o test_standalone
OS is: Linux
Sources: 1 Auto-dependencies: True
   embedding: /home/minx/usb/cs/test.exe
   embedding: /usr/lib/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll
Compiling:
as -o temp.o temp.s
cc -ggdb -o test_standalone -Wall temp.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs mono-2`  temp.o
Done
```

/usb/ is a mounted external usb drive. `mkbundle` is invoked as root. When I try to run the result binary:

```
./test_standalone

Native stacktrace:

Debug info from gdb:

Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates 
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries
used by your application.
```

and returns to the shell. The binary doesn't give any additional info. Did I miss a flag for this specific architecture?

Comment: what version of mono is this?

Comment: looks recent enough, you should probably file a bug in http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/